# HP Perf Center Start new iteration every n seconds

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I'm beginner with Perf Center, loadRunner, etc...
In perf center, I understand that if I check, in Pacing configuration, "Start new iteration at Fixed interval, every 10 seconds" it will start a new iteration every 10 seconds but it seems it will wait the end of previous iteration...

There is a solution/configuration to start the next iteration even if the current iteration is not finish yet ?

Thanks,
Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covered in Training.   If the iteration pacing interval is less than the time to complete the iteration, then the new iteration will start immediately upon completion of the previous iteration.

My guess is that you are not including think time and attempting to reproduce the load of a larger number of users with a smaller license. This path is doomed to failure for many reasons.

Turn on think time.  Pace appropriately.   Include a larger number of users.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Actually, I tried to run 1000 users without thinktime & pacing with "start new iteration at fixed intervals, every 10 seconds".
I want to run each iteration even current iteration didn't finish.

For exemple, if iteration (for some reason) runs 15s instead of 10s, I wonder if it's possible to force the execution of next iteration (it will start a the same time of the current iteration hat is still going on.

Hope you understand my question.
Thanks

Comment: If you start a new iteration while the previous iteration is still going it is effectively starting a new vuser, hence see the original answer.

Comment: Ok I understand. So If I run with only 1 vuser, it will start the new iteration only after completion of the previous one. And if I've more than 1 vuser it will start the next iteration with the current vuser only if the current iteration is done or it will start with the next vuser. Did I understand right ?

Comment: I found what I want but I need to update "HP Performance Center" from 12.50 to 12.60.
In workloadtypes, I see that we can choose (in 12.60) Goal-Oriented Schedule.
Select this workload type to define the goals you want your test to achieve. You can specify the number of Vusers to run simultaneously, or the number of Hits or Transactions Per Second. Performance Center automatically builds a schedule based on the selected goals. [link](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/pc/en/12.60-12.61/online_help/Content/PC/t_distribute_vusers_among_vuser_groups.htm#Distribute_Vusers_by_goal)

Comment: running without thinktime or pacing is a model violation for client server model and makes your test a zero predictor for actual end user usage